# How can "Dense plasma focus" be translated?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Does anybody know how to translate "dense plasma focus"?

I would like to start the German Wikipedia article, but I don't know how this is called in German.

> A **dense plasma focus** (DPF) is a machine that produces, by
>   electromagnetic acceleration and compression, a short-lived plasma
>   that is hot and dense enough to cause nuclear fusion and the emission
>   of X-rays and neutrons.

Source: [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_fusion)

Comment: Apparently there is no particular term in German for this device. You might want to simply use  *Dense Plasma Focus* as this term is used also in German when referring to it, [e. g. in this list of *Kernfusionsreaktoren*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernfusionsreaktor#Liste_von_Versuchsanlagen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a translation from ["Langenscheidt Routledge German dictionary of physics"](http://books.google.at/books?id=vai7wiq5HIYC&pg=PA356&lpg=PA356&dq=dense%20plasma%20focus&source=bl&ots=_Js288IgX3&sig=v8z57lj0lGkXO2WxELuoEimOH5c&hl=de&sa=X&ei=gkewU7mBOJKV7Aayn4CACg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=dense%20plasma%20focus&f=false):

The translation given there is:

> Einrichtung mit dichtem Plasmafokus (PI)